# Show that if x is an integer such that $x^2=x \pmod{ p^k}$, then $x=0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod{ p^k}$ for $p$ is prime and $k$ positive integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is how I did this, is this a correct proof?

$x^2-x=np^k$ for $n$ is some integer
then factorise into $x(x-1)=np^k$
So $p^k|x(x-1).$
Now suppose $p^k|x$ and $p^k|x-1$, we will have $p^k|x-(x-1)=1$ which is not possible since $p$ is prime. So $p^k|x$ or $p^k|x-1$. 
Hence,  $x=0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod {p^k}$.

Any comments please?

Comment: Looks relatively good to me! Well, a minor quibble. It might be possible that the $p^k$ factor is split between $x$ and $(x-1)$. But still you are able to deduce that... so that $p\mid x-(x-1)$ and...

Comment: Show (essentially like in your proof) that $p$ cannot divide both $x$ and $x-1$. From this conclude that $p^k$ is relatively prime to at least one of $x$ or $x-1$. It follows that $\dots$.

Comment: So you are saying that I have to show that there isn't any p^s and p^r for 0<r,s<k such that p^s|x and p^r|x-1 ?

So in additional, 
since p^k|x(x-1) then p|x(x-1). Since p|x or p|x-1 by some proposition, so p^k|x or p^k|x-1. The problem now is, how am I suppose to explain concretely that p|x or p|x-1 means p^k|x or p^k|x-1?

@AndréNicolas

Comment: If we have prime factorizations $\rm\, x = p^i a,\ x-1 = p^j b,\,\ p\nmid a,b,\,$ then $\rm\, i+j \ge k,\,$ and $\rm\,i=0\,$ or $\rm\,j=0\,$ (else $\rm\,p\mid x,x-1\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,p\mid x-(x-1)=1).\ $ So $\rm\:i = 0\:\Rightarrow\: j\ge k\:$ and $\,\ldots\ $

Comment: You can deduce that one of $x$ and $x-1$ is not divisible by $p$ at all, so what does that tell you about $i$ or $j$?

Comment: This is rather confusing!

So from math gems, let x=p^ia, x-1=p^jb, where a,b are primes by not prime p. Shouldn't i+j=k? since x and x-1 are coprime and x(x-1)=np^k? 

@JyrkiLahtonen I don't really get what you mean....

Comment: Sally, yes, $i+j=k$, you got that right. I was hinting that you might be able to prove that either $i=0$ or $j=0$. For if both are positive, then $p$ divides both $x$ and $x-1$.... If one of $i,j$ is zero, then the other is equal to $k$ and ...

Comment: Okay, what if I do it this way instead.
x^-x=np^k, x(x-1)=np^k. So p^k|x(x-1). Now let x=p^ia and x-1=p^jb, and i+j=k. Then let hcf(x,x-1)=p^t=1 since they are coprimes. so t=0. This means that either i=0 or j=0. Hence, p^k|x or p^k|x-1.

Is this a watertight proof?? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Uses marginally more machinery.

Comment: Yup, Sally. Well done! Why don't you write that up as an answer? Then we can upvote it!